# Upload multiple media entities at once

Tags: 8, media

Is there any solution yet which allows me to upload multiple media entities at once? At the moment I've to

- Select a file
- Upload it
- Select the next file
- Upload this

Especially for a gallery, where I've to upload a lot of images, this can be very annoying.

I really like to use the media entity module for this job because this way I can reuse all the images I've already uploaded in my gallery for other content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already checked the [PlUPload module](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload_widget) ?

It's still -dev, but should work ..

Another approach could be:
Using [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce) browser, that already allows multi-file uploads
in combination with [filefield_sources](https://www.drupal.org/node/2608832), you should then be able to select the uploaded images for your gallery field and others.

> More sophisticated is the [media(-entity)-suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity), there's
>   [dropzoneJS](https://www.drupal.org/project/dropzonejs) in place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I went with the PlUpload solution. Works like a charm :-). Although it's not really obvious that the integration of a JS library will add the functionallity for creating media entities in bulk ;-).

Comment: just added another option - ;)

Comment: In Drupal 8.5.6-dev / lightning-8.x-3.x-dev PlUpload doesn't seem necessary now for multiple file uploads: It is possible to pick more than one file at the same time, from the pop-up chooser shown. I have found this to be the case when clicking "Choose Files" when creating or editing content with a File field that has the "unlimited" upload setting. I'm not sure if my finding also applies to earlier pure Drupal 8 version (i.e not lightning.) I would bear in mind licensing of plupload - have a look at the library's website. The GPL variant may be unsuitable for some,

Comment: All that said. I'd still be interested (and grateful) in how @TiMESPLiNTER setup PlUpload.

Comment: With the possible licensing restrictions with PlUpload, I think that dropzoneJS would be worth considering.

Comment: I used the dropzonejs solution and this works very well. I will try to write instructions when I get a chance. +1 to @rémy's answer for the suggestion

Comment: So many years later, Plupload module is STILL not working and the file widget is still not covered by Drupal’s security advisory policy.

Comment: @MrUpsidown - with Drupal 8 its really no longer any need for PlUpload. dropzoneJS (although still in alpha) is the successor imo.